# Permissions issue automating a shell script in /usr/local/bin using launchd?

Tags: catalina, launchd, server.app

Goal: use a launchdaemon to periodically run a shell script

Environment: macOS Catalina 10.15.3, macOS Server 5.9

I have a shell script to back up Open Directory in macOS Server:

```
#!/bin/bash

dst="thePath"
pass="thepassword"

host=$(hostname)
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M)

serveradmin command <<-EOC
    dirserv:backupArchiveParams:archivePassword = $pass
    dirserv:backupArchiveParams:archivePath = ${dst}/od_backup-${host}-${date}
    dirserv:command = backupArchive

EOC
```

Permissions:

```
-rwx------  1 root  wheel  371  2 Mar 10:32 /usr/local/bin/od_backup.sh
```

Running this command in Terminal:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/od_backup.sh
```

…works as expected creating an archive sparseimage in the path specified in the script.

I then created a launchdaemon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>dk.rtm.od_backup</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>root</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/od_backup.sh</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

which I load with

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/dk.rtm.od_backup.plist
```

But system.log reports:

```
Mar  2 10:33:19 fms com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (dk.rtm.od_backup[93894]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
Mar  2 10:33:19 fms com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (dk.rtm.od_backup[93894]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
```

and when i try to start it manually with:

```
launchctl start dk.rtm.od_backup
```

I get:

```
Mar  2 10:33:32 fms com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (dk.rtm.od_backup[93919]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 13: Permission denied: /usr/local/bin/od_backup.sh
```

Questions: 
Why does launchd produce a permission denied error in this scenario?
What is the fix?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `UserName` key? Daemons in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` should already have sufficient privileges.

Comment: @TedWrigley The UserName key wasn't in there to begin with. I just added it as a test. Same error message either way…

Comment: Interesting. Well, the two options that spring to mind are (1) add the `GroupName` key with the value `wheel` to the plist, on the assumption the system is guessing the wrong group, or (2) loosen the restrictions on the script to 754 or 744.

Comment: @TedWrigley Added GroupName wheel: same result. The script contains the encryption pw for the OD archive, so I'd prefer restricting it to root only…

Comment: Ok, so I double-checked, and if your plist is in /Library/LaunchDaemons it will automatically run as root. The `UserName` and `GroupName` keys are unnecessary and irrelevant. That means your permissions error is either with the permissions settings of the plist file (which I imagine should be owned by root and set to 644) or of the script file (which I imagine should be owned by root and set to 744 or 755). Have you checked/tried that?

Comment: @TedWrigley Permissions on the script are 700, see the original post above. For the plist: `-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  718  4 Mar 16:34 dk.rtm.od_backup.plist`. I suspect the issue is related to changes made to security in Catalina, but I couldn't find any relevant documentation…

Comment: Yes, I know what the permissions *are*, I'm suggesting you *change* them to give read (and maybe execute) permission to users other than root. There's no harm in it, and you can always change it back, but for all you or I know launchd is throwing an error because one of its subprocesses can't read the file one it needs to. Sorry to suggest trial and error, but as you yourself noted documentation is sketchy.